# Laravel Livewire redirect route issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

[image]

[image]

web.php
[image: web.php]

EditChurch.php (Component)

[image]

```
<button wire:click="updateChurch">Save</button>
```

The edit button at church list page

```
<button href="{{ route('super.churches.edit', ['church' => $church->id]) }}">Edit</button>
```

I'm fairly new to livewire and not sure if its a problem of livewire to begin with. Basically I noticed this issue that happens every now in then in my project. The screenshot attached is what's happening at the server side. What's happening here is that I'm at the edit page (.../churches/edit/30), when I click the save button, it should save the data and redirect back to the list page (/churches). From what I can tell from the console, it attempts to redirect to "churches" (/churches) then attempts refresh the edit page (30) => /churches/edit/30, which eventually succeeds and stay at the edit page without any redirection. Any idea what is happening? Is it a network issue? Code issue?

Short version:
I'm at the edit page, save data redirect back to list

1. /churches/edit/30
2. /churches (I want to be here)

But what's happening now is

1. /churches/edit/30
2. /churches (cancelled)
3. /churches/edit/30 (cancelled)
4. /churches/edit/30 (cancelled)
5. /churches/edit/30 (cancelled)
6. ...
7. /churches/edit/30 (remained here)

Comment: You should send your controllers and routes, so people could help you solve the issue.

Comment: Haven't seen this with Livewire before, so I'm guessing it's a matter of implementation. You should share the relevant code, otherwise it'll be impossible to say

Comment: @EHFShahab I have updated with relevant code, let me know if you need more

Comment: @Qirel Updated with relevant information, let me know if it suffice

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary that stands out there. Never seen this issue before, so I'm not sure - but what does the requests that get cancelled look like?

Comment: @Qirel All it does is attempts to redirect and fails to do so :/ I don't encounter it as often thus I cant really replicate the issue. It happens randomly, just afraid it might be an issue that I am not aware of in the long run

Comment: I have never used `redirectRoute`. Where even did you get that from? I couldn't even find it in the docs. The [docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/redirecting) state to just redirect as per normal Laravel, so `return redirect()->to()` or `return redirect()->route()`